Function different from the null function on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support whose Fourier transform also has compact support.
Problem: "Decide if there exists a function different from the null function on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support whose Fourier transform also has compact support. If it exists, give an example of such a function."
I am trying to prove that it does not exist. I have tried the following:
As a consequence of the Paley-Wiener Theorem, if $ f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ f $ has compact support, then $ \hat{f}(\xi) $ with $ \xi \in \mathbb{C} $ defines an entire function.
If $ \hat{f}(\xi) $, considered as a function on $ \mathbb{R} $, had compact support, then $ \hat{f}(\xi) = 0 $ outside a closed interval. Since this set has accumulation points in $ \mathbb{C} $, it would follow from the Principle of Analytic Continuation that $ \hat{f}(\xi) = 0 \quad \forall \xi \in \mathbb{C} $.
I don't know how to follow the proof anymore, can someone help me, please?

If $\hat{f}$ has compact support, it is identically zero on some line segment hence the open mapping theorem shows that it is identically zero. Parseval's theorem  (well Plancherel) shows that $f$ is essentially zero.

Thank you @copper.hat !!! I have other similar recent open questions. If you want to take a look. I would appreciate it!!!

@copper.hat You're right, Plancherel is the way to go. Carleson's theorem is overkill.

For more information search for Uncertainty Principle.

@geetha290krm I do not know exactly what you mean. I have never heard abour it. But if you could explain me the relation between my problem (I understood the solution proposed by copper.hat) and the Uncertainty Principle, I would be grateful, because it is something new for me :D

After having established that $\hat f(\xi)=0$ for all $\xi\in \mathbb C$, Carleson's theorem shows that $f=0$ in $L^2$ (i.e. almost everywhere).

Then, It follows that the only compactly supported function in $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $ \hat{f}(\xi) $ has compact support is the zero function, does not it?

@NicoZimmer The zero function has compact support (its support is the empty set).
